# Using Magento 2 API

Tags: magento2, api

I want to use the Magento2 API to connect the shop with a middleware to create products.
I use Postman to test the API response. The documentation says I have to create a token, I did it. then I use my admin credentials to connect to the API but I get the answer :

```
{
    "message": "You need more permissions to access this."
}
```

could anyone describe step by step how does it work ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

After a long search I figured out that Magento API doesnt allow token generation after 6 failed temptation. So I cleared the table *`oauth_token_request_log`* and sent a POST request with my username and password **in body**
https://www.myshop.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token
then I got an answer with the token which I use later **in Header** this way *

*`Authorization : Bearer the_token_I_got`*